# Why does "Http error bad requst 400.0" displys in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new in Asp.net I need your help please. I have created an MVC scaffolding project. At the beginning, Everything was working fine. then I changed the name of Primary keys (was id to EmployeeId) and make sure to change them in the controller and views. I am able to create new records but when I click on edit, details, or delete links it shows error page http error bad request 400.0 althugh the url is correct.

snipping Code for Tbl_employeeController:

```
enter code here
    // GET: Tbl_Employee/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? EmployeeId)
    {
    if (EmployeeId == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
        Tbl_Employee tbl_Employee = db.Tbl_Employee.Find(EmployeeId);
         if (tbl_Employee == null)
          {
             return HttpNotFound();
          }
         return View(tbl_Employee);
        }

 // GET: Tbl_Employee/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? EmployeeId)
        {
            if (EmployeeId == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Tbl_Employee tbl_Employee = db.Tbl_Employee.Find(EmployeeId);
            if (tbl_Employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.DepId = new SelectList(db.Tbl_Department, "DepartmentId", "DepName", tbl_Employee.DepId);
            return View(tbl_Employee);
        }

        // POST: Tbl_Employee/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "EmployeeId,EmpName,Position,Nationality,Last_W_D,Head_of_Dep,Status,EmpEmail,EmpPassword,SignaturePath,DepId")] Tbl_Employee tbl_Employee)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tbl_Employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.DepId = new SelectList(db.Tbl_Department, "DepartmentId", "DepName", tbl_Employee.DepId);
            return View(tbl_Employee);
        }

        // GET: Tbl_Employee/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? EmployeeId)
        {
            if (EmployeeId == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Tbl_Employee tbl_Employee = db.Tbl_Employee.Find(EmployeeId);
            if (tbl_Employee == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(tbl_Employee);
        }

        // POST: Tbl_Employee/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int EmployeeId)
        {
            Tbl_Employee tbl_Employee = db.Tbl_Employee.Find(EmployeeId);
            db.Tbl_Employee.Remove(tbl_Employee);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

snipping Code for Index.cshtml:

```
<td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.EmployeeId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.EmployeeId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.EmployeeId })
    </td>
```

the error page:
[http error bad requst 400.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U8JA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid when you debug you code you will find the input parameter `EmployeeId` is null.

My suggestion is changing your code `public ActionResult Details(int? EmployeeId)`  to `public ActionResult Details(int? id)` and have a try.

The reason is that in your MVC project, default route rule is `{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}` that means when you send request like `GET: Tbl_Employee/Details/5`, you need to set the input parameter of your method as `int? id` but not other parameter name.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked, but many questions raise: 1-  public ActionResult Details(int? id) that means this "id" has nothing to do with database, because pk is "EmployeeId"? 2- Can I change the default route rule so it maches with the one in database? Can you please give futher explanation. thanks in advance.

Comment: You can change the default route, but it will also influence other actions. My idea is using `public ActionResult Details(int? id){ string EmployeeId=id; xxx}`. Or some other methods.